# Bundling react framework with rollup into multiple chunks loses reference to ThemeProvider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, config, rollup

I am using a rollup.config.js file to bundle and build my react app (this is on github) for importing purposes into multiple different projects. My react app is essentially a framework that has different folders containing components like buttons, dropdowns, tables etc. While I currently do have a working version of my config that builds and bundles the app properly, it only chunks it to one single index.js file in the dist folder. I am able to write import statements like

```
import { Button } from 'framework-react/dist'
```

but my goal is to be able to write import statements in the form of

```
import { Button } from 'framework-react/dist/buttons'
and 
import { Table } from 'framework-react/dist/tables'
```

(the same folder structure as my framework react app).
My project that i am importing components into, is wrapped in a custom ThemeProvider and when I try and bundle into different files instead of one, I lose reference and the ThemeProvider stops working. Any tips on what I can do to solve this issue? Here is my rollup.config.js for reference:

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import visualizer from 'rollup-plugin-visualizer';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

export default   {
  input: {
    index: 'src/index',
  },
  output: {
    dir: 'dist',
    format: 'umd',
    name: 'Framework',
    globals: {
      react: 'React',
      'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
      'prop-types': 'PropTypes',
      uuid: 'uuid',
      'react-virtualized': 'AutoSizer',
      xlsx: 'XLSX',
    },
  },
  external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'prop-types', 'uuid', 'xlsx', 'react-virtualized'],
  plugins: [
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      runtimeHelpers: true,
    }),
    external(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    visualizer(),
    terser(),
  ],
};
```

Comment: Hi @milo, were you able to solve this?